# Running Hugo from a PHP exec() function

Tags: php, git, github, continuous-deployment, hugo

I'm attempting to setup a continuous deployment script for Hugo on a LAMP stack server, and the last snag I'm running into is getting Hugo to run.

**The Background**

I have Hugo and PHP installed on a VPS, and for my app, two directories:

1. `public`, where my actual site lives.
2. `hugo`, where my entire Hugo setup gets pulled into from GitHub.

I'm using a GitHub webhook to ping my `deploy.php` script when I merge into the `master` branch. Here's the relevant part of that script:

```
// 1. Pull the latest build from GitHub
exec('cd /path/to/hugo && git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/master');

// 2. Run Hugo to compile any new posts and pages into HTML
exec('cd /path/to/hugo && hugo');

// 3. Copy the files in the /public directory from Hugo into the /public app directory
exec('cd /path/to/hugo && cp -r /path/to/hugo/public/. public');
```

**What's happening**

Items 1 and 3 run. Item 2 does not.

More clearly stated: the latest build pulls from GitHub, and any files I've built ahead of time are copied from the Hugo build into the `/public` directory.

I cannot get `hugo` to run via `exec()`, though, and I'm not entirely sure why.

If I SSH into the server in a terminal window, `cd` into the `/path/to/hugo` directory, and run `hugo` there, everything compiles as expected, which eliminates things like, "Maybe Hugo is installed wrong" or "Maybe Hugo isn't accessible in that directory".

So... what am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this is a path issue, meaning by default, a bash session won't execute a program just because you are in the right folder: you have to specify its path (in your case: the current folder)

That means: replace `&& hugo` with `&& ./hugo`

Or, as the [OP Chris Ferdinandi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1293256/chris-ferdinandi) did ([comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218338/running-hugo-from-a-php-exec-function#comment83438725_48220406)), you can use an absolute path:

> I ssh-ed into the server and ran `which hugo` to get the appropriate path, and replaced `&& hugo` with that.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much.

For anyone else reading this, I ssh-ed into the server and ran `which hugo` to get the appropriate path, and replaced `&& hugo` with that.

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Cheers! I'm a front-end guy fumbling my way through some backend stuff (terrifying words, right?), so greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: @ChrisFerdinandi No problem: we are *all* fumbling our way through stuff ;-)